# Script to Save a copy of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to find a way of creating a script that will copy a GoogleSheet, which is the Master file, into a new location with a new name.  The name of the file would be located in Cell A1 with the folder location in Cell A2.  With Excel it was relatively easy, but I just can't seem to get anything to work with GoogleSheets.

Comment: You mean Drive folders? Apps Script works on a server-side.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is the Master file:

[image: example]

Replace cell `A2` with the `folder id` of the destination folder, choose the name of the copy in cell `A1` and change `Sheet1` to your specific case.

Copy and execute this function from the script editor:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  const new_name = sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  const dest_folder_id = sh.getRange('A2').getValue();
 
  const dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dest_folder_id);
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(new_name, dest_folder);
}
```

**References:**

- [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination)
- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Comment: Thanks - that is great